# TypeError: _ember.default.HTMLBars._registerHelper is not a function

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower

I updated my app with some new packages.  Now, I'm getting an error in my browser debugger console:

`TypeError: _ember.default.HTMLBars._registerHelper is not a function`

I launch `ember server` and none of my content displays in the generated index.html.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "2.4.2",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^1.1.1",
    "broccoli-static-compiler": "^0.2.2",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker": "0.5.5",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.5.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-i18n": "0.0.6",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-inline-content": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "1.5.3",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "2.3.3",
    "ember-export-application-global": "1.0.5",
    "ember-infinity": "0.2.1",
    "ember-modal-dialog": "0.8.3",
    "ember-moment": "6.0.0",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-cli": "1.13.15",
    "ember-validations": "2.0.0-alpha.4"
  }
}
```

`bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.3.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "1.1.3",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.5",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.7",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.0",
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.4.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "components": "git+http://CinGitLab01.paycor.com/UI/components.git#0.8.0",
    "ember-uploader": "0.3.11",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "~0.6.2",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "~1.5.1",
    "lodash": "~4.0.1",
    "moment": ">= 2.10.6",
    "moment-timezone": ">= 0.2.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ember": "2.3.0",
    "qunit-notifications": "~0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.1.3",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.5",
    "loader.js": "3.2.0",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.7",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.2.5",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "moment": "~2.10.5",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.0"
  }
}
```

I went through and tried to update each package to the latest version.  However, I had to revert some because of dependencies on earlier versions.

The application does use helpers and they look like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import dates from 'MyApp/util/dates';
export function formatDate(params/*, hash*/) {
    return dates.timestamp.toDateTimeString(params[0]);
}

export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(formatDate);
```

and

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import dates from 'My/util/dates';
export function formatDate(params/*, hash*/) {
    return dates.timestamp.toDateString(params[0]);
}

export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(formatDate);
```

Comment: It looks like you've added a package that uses the old method for registering helpers in your application. Do you know exactly which package you added that caused the error?

Comment: @JustinNiessner I tried updating from Ember 1.X to Ember 2.X and it opened this can of worms.

Comment: Yeah. I recently went through the same process. It's easiest to incrementally upgrade to each minor release between your current version and 2.x fixing all of the deprecation warnings along the way.

Comment: Does your application use helpers? How are they defined?

Comment: @locks Yes.  Updated question

Comment: @JustinNiessner - When do the depreciation warnings appear?  Is it sufficient to just update bower.json and run bower install (similarly for npm)?  Or do I need to run ember server too?

Comment: You'll see the deprecation warnings in the browser console when you run the application.

Answer (score 1):

`Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper` is the older API, which I think was deprecated in 1.13 and then removed in 2.0. If you change it to `Ember.Helper.helper` it should work.

You can also consult the relevant [deprecation entry](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_handlebars-htmlbars-helpers).

Comment: Good to know this information.  I am still getting this error after making this change.

Comment: Hm, do the addons you're using provide helpers? They might need updating.